# One parameter return null of two parameters called by ActionResult Post method, so i get NullrefernceException was unhandled by user code. mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I called two parameters to ActionResult Post method. One collected my models and the other is object of HttpPostedFileBase.
**The reason behind that error because** one of them return null(yesterday was HttpPostedFileBase object null, **Now my model(Allmodels) return Null only when i call it with this method in the same time with the other parameter.**
These images showing the error:

[image]

[image]

**If i only call one parameter alone** to handle it everything is fine!  **but the problem occurs when i call both!**

Here is my ActionResult Post Method Code:

```
SWMModelContainer db = new SWMModelContainer();
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult uploadImg(ViewModel.AllModels allmodels, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var post = new ViewModel.AllModels();
    TryUpdateModel(post);
    // Post _post = db.Posts.Find(1);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var context = new SWMModelContainer();
        var useremail = User.Identity.Name;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(useremail))
        {
            var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == useremail);
            post.posts.UserUrId = user.UrId;
        }
        post.posts.Date = DateTime.Now;
        post.posts.Text = allmodels.posts.Text;
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Contents/Img");
        string pathTodb = "~/Contents/Img/";
        if (file != null)
        {
            string imgName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // string fullImgName = userid.users.FirstName.ToString() + imgName ;
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Contents/Img"), "12279_" + imgName);

            file.SaveAs(path);
            pathTodb = "~/Contents/Img/" + imgName;
        }
        post.posts.ImgUrl = pathTodb;
        db.Posts.Add(post.posts);
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "main");
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@model SwmMvcDemo.ViewModel.AllModels
@{Layout = null;}
<h2>uploadImg</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("uploadImg", "main", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name ="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" name="uploadImg" />
}
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(t => t.posts.Title )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.posts.Title)
</div>

<label>Post Description</label>
<div class="content">
    @Html.EditorFor(t => t.posts.Text)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.posts.Text)
</div>
```

And here is my model:

```
public class AllModels
{
    public User users { get; set; }
    public Comment comments { get; set; }
    public Post posts { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> UsersCollection { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Comment> CommentsCollection { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Post> PostsCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Please help, i'm with this issue from yesterday till now!

Comment: Can you try after remove the Httppostedfilebase parameter. and read the file by check if request have any file uploaded by request.files something ?

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha that will be undefined variable i got error.. Stephen solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form only posts back the values of form controls within its element. Your form only contains 1 element (the `<input type="file" .../>`) so that is all that is submitted.

If you want to submit the value of `posts.Title` and `posts.Text` then move the associated `EditorFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` methods inside the form.

Side note: You do not need `TryUpdateModel(post);` (and in fact it will always fail) - your method has a parameter `AllModels allmodels` which contains a property for `Post posts` so it will be validated when the model is bound. You also need to remove all reference to `post` (e.g. `post.posts.Date = DateTime.Now;`) and instead use `allmodels.posts`. There are multiple other issues with your code but this should get you started.

Comment: Works !! and your side node totally right. i actually beginner but working hard on a project. Any suggested solutions for my issues ?  Thank u so much.

Comment: Some other issues: If `ModelState` is invalid you still redirect so the poor user has no idea its failed and the `post` was not added to the database or the file was not saved. `<label>Post Description</label>` generates a label which is not a label (clicking on it does not set focus to the associated control)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that ViewModel is the Folder name and AllModels is actually a view model which contains all other model classes. If so, then just change your Action Method.
Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult uploadImg(AllModels allmodels, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     //Check whether above allmodels is having data or not first
      var post = new AllModels(); 
     //Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: already did that early but not working. the problem not with post variable at all and i deleted that row after Stephen answer.. u can see Stephen answer